# Merge rows based on column value and value different column in next row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with two columns: "From" and "To"

```
From  To
a     b
b     c
c     d
e     f
```

I would like to check if the "From" on the next row is the same as the "To" in the current row. If so, then the "To" in the current row can be substituted with the next "To". Also, the next row can be deleted.

This has to continue/loop until no row has a "To" which is the same as the next line's "From".

The end result would look like this:

```
From  To
a     d
e     f
```

I'm stuck here... Can't figure out how to pass/delete the rows so that the endresult is achieved...

Comment: Hi Wimpel, in which step are you stuck? Could you show the code you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for your example.

```
data.frame("From"=df$From[c(TRUE, head(df$To, -1) != tail(df$From, -1))], 
           "To"=df$To[c(head(df$To, -1) != tail(df$From, -1), TRUE)])
  From To
1    a  d
2    e  f
```

It works by offsetting the order of the From and To vectors, to include the first From element and the last To element, and compare subsequent From elements with the preceding To element.

Comment: To get a better idea, check out the output of `c(head(df$To, -1)` and `tail(df$From, -1)` then `c(head(df$To, -1) != tail(df$From, -1), TRUE)` should make sense as a logical vector. This logical vector is used to subset `df$To` for example.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work,

Breaking the dataframe into separate elements by row (`c(t(df))`). Using `rle` finding those elements which has 2 consecutive values and removing them (`x$lengths != 2`). Making the remaining elements into dataframe again with `ncol = 2` as we know there are only two columns in this.

```
x <- rle(c(t(df)))
setNames(data.frame(matrix(x$values[x$lengths != 2],ncol = 2,byrow = T)), c("From", "To"))

#  From To
#1    a  d
#2    e  f
```

Let me know if you find some corner cases, where this doesn't work.